# Quartz.Net - How to assign trigger when using JobFactory

Tags: c#, quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

ok, this is a newbie question, i searched through the net couldn't found any clue, here is my problem:

from the example usualy trigger and job scheduled by using `IScheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger)` now i used JobFactory i tried to use `IScheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger)` but ends with **Trigger's related Job's name cannot be null** exception

here is my simplyfied code:

**Job**

```
class DummyJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("executed");
    }
}
```

**Job Factory**

```
class JobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return new DummyJob();
    }
}
```

**Main Program**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sc = sf.GetScheduler();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .ForJob()
            .StartAt(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5))
            .Build();

        sc.JobFactory = new JobFactory();
        sc.ScheduleJob(trigger);
        sc.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("waiting...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        sc.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as scheduling is concerning, I don't think you should be doing anything different just because you are using your own JobFactory.

Your main program is invalid because it doesn't know what job you want to schedule.

Your example is probably over simplified and doesn't give a clear idea or what you are trying to achieve with your JobFactory, but perhaps its worth pointing out that the purpose of a JobFactory is not to specify **which** job to run, but to specify **how** a particular job is supposed to start and hence is expecting bundle.JobDetail to contain the information about which job to run.